# Addition with the help of varag and enhanced for loop

Tags: java

Hi i am trying to do the addition with the help of "varags" and" enhanced for loop".But i am getting this marker "This method must return a result of type int".

```
class Hello1 {
int pluss(int...v){
int plus=0;
for(int x :v){
plus=plus+x;
System.out.println(plus);
return plus;            
}
}}
public class Addition{
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Hello1 h1=new Hello1();
    h1.pluss(3,7,9,10);
}}
```

Comment: -1 for continually updating the code and post. This is now the third, completely different question. For follow-ups, use comments or post new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hello1 hl=new Hello1();
h1.pluss(3,7,9,10);
```

Just a typo, use better fonts...

`h1` versus `hl`.

Comment: Can you please look into the new error i m facing!!

Answer (score 4):

You are re-declaring `plus` every loop, which is useless. Declare it before the loop and accumulate the total. Consider also returning it:

```
static int pluss(int...v){
    int plus=0;
    for(int x :v){
        plus += x;
    }
    System.out.println(plus);
    return plus;
}
```

Also note how the method can be static, because it doesn't use any instance fields.

Comment: To fix your current error, move the return statement *outside* the loop (ie after the next brace - like in my code)